# How to use multiple files selection on upload file input in old Browsers?

Tags: php, html

I need to select multiple files and I found one way to do this. But that way only works on newest browsers, using attribute "multiple" on input.

I didnt found any solution on internet.

Can anyone help me to find a solution?

I'm able to use HTML, PHP, JavaScript (jQuery).

Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native solution to multiple file selection uploading in older browsers. This requires some kind of plugin technology, typically Flash or Java.

I personally use [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/). It will seamlessly switch between HTML5 and Flash (among others) based on the user's browser. There are plenty of other Flash or Java multi-file upload solutions out there as well.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to use Plupload.

Answer (score 1):

I think the traditional solution to this is to allow multiple file input elements; like this.

File 1: [***_*____**] (Browse...)

File 2: [***_*____**] (Browse...)

*Upload more files...*

If the user needs more, just have them click a button at the bottom to create them. At some points, YouTube would allow you to use a Java applet-based upload dialog as well; but since then the opinion of Java applet security has faded quite a lot and most people avoid it entirely.

Having multi-selection is a real benefit to modern browsers, and one that's not really so easy to emulate in the older ones.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and explanation, but I need to select more multiple files at once. I'll try to use Java or Flash solutions like @jszobody suggested